# Object Oriented Meteor

Tags: javascript, oop, meteor

I created some objects on the server side:

```
Scoreboard={
   update:function() {.. }, 
   Home:null, 
   etc. 
} 
Game={
    more args and meths
} 
Player={idem}
```

I'm trying to run some of those objects methods from the client by using Meteor.call() but it doesn't work. Further, when I add them to Meteor.methods(),  the methods that have dependencies on other objects methods doesn't work either.

It runs properly on client. Chaos begins when I try to do the same at the server side.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Got the solution from Brett

Comment: Required reading for oo-meteor: https://dweldon.silvrback.com/models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a call from the client to the server, you will need to use `Meteor.call()`. If you are on the server side and you want to make a call to a meteor method, you will need to use `Meteor.call()`. If your code is structured and declared the way you have it above, then you should be able to directly access it just fine. An example would be:

```
//CLIENT SIDE
Template.foo.events({
    'click #startNewGame': function() {
        Meteor.call('startNewGame');
    }
});

//SERVER SIDE
Meteor.methods({
    'startNewGame': function() {
        Game.newGame();
    }
});
Scoreboard={
   update:function() {.. }, 
   Home:null, 
   etc. 
} 
Game={
    newGame: function() {..},
    more args and meths
} 
Player={idem}
```

Comment: Thank you Brett. I get what I'm totally messing up.